# Why the data does not print out with eclipse in Ubuntu c++?

Tags: c++

I am using Eclipse in the Ubuntu operation system and trying to print out this data from the begin to the string "END OF HEADER" but I do not understand why it did not give me the one as I expected.

I also used another file with the tail ".17n" to test and it worked, but the file that I am trying to use is "CAS100ATA_R_20160100000_01D_EN.rnx" and did not work and the data still sticking in the while loop. 2 these data files have exactly the same format, but maybe different tail format, such as: ".17n" and ".rxn" I do not know how to get this out.

If anyone whoever can help, I appreciated for that help!

Here are my code and attached data file.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <csignal>
    #include <cstdio>
    using namespace std;

    const int MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE = 81;

   nt main () {
  string filename = "GANP00SVK_R_20160100000_01D_EN.rnx";

    ifstream            fin;
    fin.open(filename.c_str());
    int head_lines = 0;
    std::string header_end =("END OF HEADER");
    char line[MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE];

    while (1) // scanning data per line until hit the message "END OF HEADER"
    {
        head_lines++;
        fin.getline(line, MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE);
        std:: string line1(line);
        std::size_t found = line1.find(header_end);

        if (found!=std::string::npos)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

  cout << "done!"<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Ops, I can not upload the data file but please follow this link, you can get CAS100ATA_R_20160100000_01D_EN.rnx file.
ftp://cddis.gsfc.nasa.gov/gnss/data/daily/2016/010/16l/

Comment: There is nothing about this code that would result in an infinite loop.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : I am sorry for the wrong code, here is update one. The previous one which you saw is the working one but i can not detect the line I want to stop reading data. The new code with ideal whenever hit the "END OF HEADER" line, it will jump out the infinity while loop, but I am still stucking in the while loop.

Comment: Because you're no longer checking that the `getline` succeeded. And why did you switch to `char` arrays?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : because in this data every single line has 81 char, and I plan to use this option to split and convert string to number for next steps.

Comment: That does not explain why you switched to `char` arrays.

Comment: Yes, std::getline with std::string can still be used and then you do not impose any limit on the input line length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new code, you are not checking that opening the file actually succeeded. Change the line to:

```
while (fin.good()) // scanning data per line until hit the message "END OF HEADER"
```

to check opening the file, because now your code is opening a file of different name than you actually claim to use. So if the file you try to open is not there, your code loops infinitely (because it did not open, fin.getline() fails and you do not read anything, so the terminating condition is never reached).

Better yet to print an error message when the file fails to open.

---

So to sum up, try with this (remove the `line` char array):

```
    if (!fin.good())
    {
        cerr << "Cannot open the file!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    string line;
    while (getline(fin, line)) // scanning data per line until hit the message "END OF HEADER"
    {
        head_lines++;
        std::size_t found = line.find(header_end);

        if (found!=std::string::npos)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is a good add, but when I run code with it, it read only the 1st line and jumped out of the while loop. It did not stop at "END OF HEADER". Do you have any ideal?

Comment: Because the file you try to open does not exist? Please check that the file name you have in the code is indeed also the file name on your drive.

Comment: yes, I did. The filename still exist on the path I added. I read the data, but read only 1st line of the data file.

Comment: Hum, actually with the file "GANP00SVK_R_20160100000_01D_EN.rnx" the problem is, that the line does not fit into the buffer. In that case the `fin.getline()` function sets the `failbit` of the `fin` so it becomes invalid and you cannot read from it any more. So withouth checking `fin.good()` you enter the infinite loop even if the file exists. Another reason to use `std::getline(fin, line)`.

Comment: (it works if you increase the buffer size e.g. to 100 but would fail again if a line in the file before header end would be longer)

Comment: It worked, I know this is weird for me, because original code I posted to ask question worked probably for my file with the tail ".17n" but I do not understand why did not work for ".rnx" file, even have the same content in the file, even I copied and pasted between 2 those file but still negative. Anyway, It worked, Thank you very much for your help,  axalis !

Comment: Actually the file is 80 char lines, however the particular file is in Windows format, so it has \r\n line terminators. If you reading under Linux (didn't try under Windows there it might work) \n is removed, but \r remains which makes the line 81 chars long. Including the terminating char it is 82 chars, so it does not fit into the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the problem.
I ran your program in the terminal (not from within Eclipse) with the input file you mention (CAS100ATA_R_20160100000_01D_EN.rnx) and I had no problems: it printed every line in the file.
I I do not see how you can have infinite loop as mentioned in the comment by @Lightness Races in Orbit .

I also checked that the `"END OF HEADER"` is detected fine in case you want to stop execution at that point by having  the extra

```
string endstring("END OF HEADER");
ifstream myfile ("CAS100ATA_R_20160100000_01D_EN.rnx");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline (myfile,line) )
        {
            if (line.find(endstring) != string::npos) {
                cout << "########## FOUND ###########" << endl;
                cout << endstring << endl;    
            }
            cout << line << endl;
```

and it was detected and printed ok...

> $ ./test_readfile
>        3.03           NAVIGATION DATA     E                   RINEX VERSION / TYPE gfzrnx-1.01-6325    FILE CONVERSION     20160111 043737
>   UTC PGM / RUN BY / DATE  GAL    7.5250e+01 -7.3050e-01  1.0280e-02 
>   0.0000e+00       IONOSPHERIC CORR     GAUT -3.7252902980e-09 1.776356840e-15 518400 1878          TIME SYSTEM CORR
>       17    17  1851     3                                    LEAP SECONDS
>
> #### FOUND ############################ END OF HEADER
>
> END OF HEADER 
>   E11 2016 01 10 01 40 00  .182084622793e-04  .109565689854e-10 
>   .000000000000e+00
>   ....
>   ....

I suggest that it might be some quirks associated with the Eclipse terminal/Console or you didn't look at the Console output for this file or you haven't setup the run configuration correctly (although only a filename is the difference according to what you say).

Also, if I put `break` when checking for END_OF_HEADER, execution will stop at the desired point.

> ./test_readfile
>        3.03           NAVIGATION DATA     E                   RINEX VERSION / TYPE gfzrnx-1.01-6325    FILE CONVERSION     20160111 043737
>   UTC PGM / RUN BY / DATE  GAL    7.5250e+01 -7.3050e-01  1.0280e-02 
>   0.0000e+00       IONOSPHERIC CORR     GAUT -3.7252902980e-09 1.776356840e-15 518400 1878          TIME SYSTEM CORR
>       17    17  1851     3                                    LEAP SECONDS
>
> #### FOUND ############################ END OF HEADER done!

Comment: so, I agree with you this point. But do you see any wrong with the new upload code, fedepad ?